# RUN npm install && npm install -g serve && npm run build takes forever to build in Docker [Resolved]

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Below is my DockerFile. I was trying to follow Docker learning content in which they were teaching how to run a container.
I cloned this project from github according to instruction in the tutorial : git clone https://github.com/docker/welcome-to-docker

And ran this command docker: build -t welcome-to-docker .

```
# Start your image with a node base image
FROM node:18-alpine

# The /app directory should act as the main application directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the app package and package-lock.json file
COPY package*.json ./

# Copy local directories to the current local directory of our docker image (/app)
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public

# Install node packages, install serve, build the app, and remove dependencies at the end
RUN npm install \
    && npm install -g serve \
    && npm run build \
    && rm -fr node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app using serve command
CMD [ "serve", "-s", "build" ]
```

This is the error I am facing

```
468.3 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
468.3 npm ERR! network aborted
468.3 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
468.3 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
468.3 npm ERR! network 
468.3 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
468.3 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
468.3 
468.3 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-03-22T20_48_04_223Z-debug-0.log
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  14 |     # Install node packages, install serve, build the app, and remove dependencies at the end
  15 | >>> RUN npm install \
  16 | >>>     && npm install -g serve \
  17 | >>>     && npm run build \
  18 | >>>     && rm -fr node_modules
  19 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install     && npm install -g serve     && npm run build     && rm -fr node_modules" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Can anyone help me here! Why is this happening ?

[image: This is what I am seeing in docker logs the process never ends or fails.]

Comment: I cloned and was able to run the container, and the server was launched - `http://localhost:8088`, seems like you are having a network issue.  try deleting `package-lock.json` and run the  `docker build -t welcome-to-docker . `